# Magento Change Product Page Titles to only include catalog, level1 and 2

Tags: magento, seo, suffix, html-title

I have a rather long and complicated category-struktur up to 5 levels of subcategories.
It is all by standard added to product-html-title.
I would like it only to show catalog, level1 and level2 subcategories.
any suggestion how to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Log into the Admin Pannel, and go to the "Catalog -> Manage Product" menu

From there select the item that you wish to update.
On the left side you will see a navigation menu with “Meta Information”.

The very first field is Meta Title.  This is the field that you need to update to change the title of the Product Page to a SEO or alternative value.